# 'Finite' Approximation of Languages

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, np-complete

Is it true, that for any finite language, there is a Turing Machine that runs in polynomial time that accepts said language?

It seems to me that this would imply that given any number $N$, any language could be 'approximated' for inputs of length at most $N$ by a polynomial running time TM.

In particular, there should be an (effective) algorithm in P that correctly solves an NP-complete problem for inputs of length at most $N$.

Is the above correct?
If it is indeed correct, what are some results regarding these kind of 'approximation'?
Are there any 'approximating' algorithms with practical importance?

PS: sorry for my poor grammar.

Comment: This Turing machine could blow up in size when $N$ goes to infinity.

Comment: @SimonMarynissen I understand this, but an effective algorithm for SAT for inputs of length $\leq N$ would still be of incredible practical importance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you're certainly correct that for any finite language $L$ there (abstractly) exists a Turing machine that runs in polynomial time (in fact, you can do as well as linear!), this doesn't necessarily mean that you can effectively solve NP-hard problems by truncating it.

To be explicit about the first part (a linear-time Turing machine that solves a given finite language $L$), you can consider the following algorithm:

- (preprocessing) construct a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) from all the strings in $L$
- now, given an input $x$, follow $x$ along the trie. If at any point the next character in $x$ is not contained in the trie, reject; otherwise, check that the node you end up at is an "accept" node and respond accordingly

Since you're just traversing a fixed tree for $|x|$-many steps, this is a linear time Turing machine. However, this doesn't mean that all languages can be effectively decided in linear time! The main issue is in *constructing* the Turing machine: given an NP-hard language $L$, suppose you truncate the problem to the (now linear-time solvable) finite language $L_{\leq N}$ of strings in $L$ of length $\leq N$.
In theory, there *exists* a Turing machine that decides $L_{\leq N}$ in linear time, but how would you construct it without knowing $L_{\leq N}$ explicitly in the first place?
To determine $L_{\leq N}$, you'd have to somehow decide for all strings $x$ of length $\leq N$ whether or not $x\in L$.

Basically, this insight can only get you this far:

> Once you (somehow) determine the set of all length $\leq N$ strings contained in a language $L$, then you can solve $L_{\leq N}$ in linear time.

However, you can see how this is cheap: assuming you've determined $L_{\leq N}$, you just need to memorise this set (it's a finite set, so it would only take finite memory).
This is similar to being able to check primality of all numbers $\leq N$ by just having a list of all prime numbers less than $N$: *constructing* this list remains a nontrivial (as in, takes more than linear time to do) task.

Analogously, consider the language $\mathsf{Halt}_{\leq N}$ of all pairs $(A,x)$ where $A$ is a Turing machine and $x$ is an input such that the encoding of this pair has length $\leq N$ and $A$ halts on $x$. It's still theoretically linear-time decidable, but how would you construct such a Turing machine?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I would love to see an algorithm that solves $L_{\leq N}$ for an NP-complete L, without memorising $L_{\leq N}$ (even though finding it is nontrivial).

Answer (score 0):

Just consider that for any NP-complete language (assuming $P \ne NP$) you need a non-polynomial time to check if even a single word belongs to it... all that *without* any further details of what you want to do (that is precisely the crux of the matter: If $P \ne NP$, it is *impossible* to solve the "Is $\sigma \in L?$" question for all $\sigma$ in polynomial time).

Comment: Even if we assume $P \neq NP$, deciding if a single word is in an NP-complete language can be fast. I heard that boolean circuits may be, in fact, effective in checking $\sigma \in L$ for all $\sigma$ with given length.

Comment: 'One might imagine that $P \neq NP$, but SAT is tractable in the following sense: for every $l$ there is a very short program that runs in $l^2$ time and correctly treats all instances of size $l$', is a quote from Karp (might be outdated though).